# Pygame time.get_fps() value

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate

I was looking at the `pygame.time.Clock.get_fps()` method and after puting it inside of the `while` loop printing and checking it some times, i see that i starts to give its value after five frames (and not 10 as said in the documentation). I did put this inside the while loop (clock is the object of the `pygame.time.Clock()` class created inside my class):

```
 print "clock.tick:", self.clock.tick(self.fps)
 print "clock.get_fps", self.clock.get_fps()
```

and the result by having the `fps=60` was:

```
clock.tick: 48
clock.get_fps 0.0
clock.tick: 16
clock.get_fps 0.0
clock.tick: 16
clock.get_fps 0.0
clock.tick: 16
clock.get_fps 0.0
clock.tick: 16
clock.get_fps 0.0
clock.tick: 16
clock.get_fps 51.8134689331
clock.tick: 16
clock.get_fps 51.8134689331
clock.tick: 16
clock.get_fps 51.8134689331
clock.tick: 16
clock.get_fps 51.8134689331
clock.tick: 16
clock.get_fps 51.8134689331
```

As one can see the first `clock.get_fps` comes out after the first 5 calls, but it supposedly should calculate the average of the last 10 calls to `tick()`. What am i missing here? Can anyone help explain this?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the implementation of [clock.tick()](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/d61ea8eabd56025fcb4ceb24d63f9a6a30fbe8d4/src/time.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#time.c-264) and where in that module the FPS value is set (search for `_clock->fps =`), the documentation seems to be correct that it determines the FPS after 10 calls (which means at the 11th call) to `tick()`. Let's try with a more isolated example:

```
import pygame

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

for i in range(20):
    print '{}: tick={}, fps={}'.format(i+1, clock.tick(fps), clock.get_fps())
```

For me, this gives:

```
1: tick=17, fps=0.0
2: tick=17, fps=0.0
3: tick=18, fps=0.0
4: tick=16, fps=0.0
5: tick=19, fps=0.0
6: tick=17, fps=0.0
7: tick=18, fps=0.0
8: tick=17, fps=0.0
9: tick=17, fps=0.0
10: tick=17, fps=0.0
11: tick=19, fps=57.1428565979
12: tick=17, fps=57.1428565979
13: tick=18, fps=57.1428565979
14: tick=16, fps=57.1428565979
15: tick=19, fps=57.1428565979
16: tick=17, fps=57.1428565979
17: tick=18, fps=57.1428565979
18: tick=16, fps=57.1428565979
19: tick=18, fps=57.1428565979
20: tick=17, fps=57.1428565979
```

Given the fact that 5 is 10 divided by 2, I'd assume that you call `clock.tick()` (or `clock.tick_busy_loop()`, which both call `clock_tick_base()` internally) either directly or indirectly somewhere else in your game loop, so each iteration has two calls to `clock.tick()`, resulting in a FPS value already after 5 loop iterations.

This is using Python 2.7.11 on OS X and PyGame from Mercurial (`pip install --user hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`), which should be revision `d61ea8eab` at the time of writing, just in case you can't reproduce it on your installation.

Answer (score 0):

What I figured out is you can do 1000 / clock.tick(60) and you would get an approcimation to the fps but it doesn't return 0 for the first 5 frames

Answer (score -1):

try this: you type this in your code (anywhere in the code will work):

```
while True:
    print(clock.getfps())
```

and BOOM! it just prints the current fps in the console!

Comment: Is this valid pygame code?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.